# infinite loop while accessing resource folder

Tags: java, spring, filter, resources

In my spring project i have written a filter to handle all requests.it works fine, but while accessing the resource an infinite loop happening.

i defined my resource folder under a class extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
this is the code that i used to define resource folder:-

this is my request url:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
http://localhost:8080/abc/resources/images/chart/receivableaccounts.png
```

while accessing this url through browser the request is proceesing number of times in console(eclipse).

i can't identify what's the real problem is.

here is my RequestFilter:

```
package org.abc.app.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.businesscognizance.app.util.Session;

/**
* <b>Custom filter created for handling all incoming,outgoing 
requests</b>
* 
* @author Jishnu
* 
*/

public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

private static Logger logger = 
LogManager.getLogger(RequestFilter.class);

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String context = httpServletRequest.getContextPath();
    String requestUri = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
    int status = httpServletResponse.getStatus();
    System.out.println("hey there>>>>" + requestUri + "check this" + context + "/resources");
    if (isAuthenticated(httpServletRequest) || requestUri.equals(context + "/login")
            || requestUri.startsWith(context + "/resources")) {

        logger.info("access granted for a device with ip address" + " '" + httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() + "' "
                + "for requested url" + " '" + httpServletRequest.getRequestURL() + "'");

        if (isAuthorized()) {

        } else {
            httpServletResponse.reset();
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            return;

        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    else {
        httpServletResponse.reset();
        if (status == HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED || status == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(status);
        }
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().println("server rejected your request");

        return;

    }

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

public boolean isAuthorized() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isAuthenticated(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String accessToken = request.getHeader("access_token");
    boolean result = false;
    if (accessToken != null) {
        if (Session.ifTokenExists(accessToken)) {
            result = true;
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

}

if you need anything further please let me know.

any suggestion will be useful.

Thank you

Comment: do you have the same class 2 times in FilterChain?

Comment: @mlecz no. this is the only filter class remains in my project

Comment: How are you making the request? Post the request URL. How do you there's an infinite loop?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar accessing through the url in browser like this http://localhost:8080/abc/resources/images/chart/receivableaccounts.png

Comment: Put that in your question, comment is not a place to provide additional info. Also clearly state the behavior you _see_ - you don't see infinite loops.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar ok

Comment: where and how is your filter defined? web.xml?

Comment: @ScaryWombat question updated, please keep in touch

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a hokey implementation of:

1. A pre-authenticated request.
2. Request for static resources.

This looks straight outta a 2003 codebase; I suggest you start by extending `OncePerRequestFilter` and make the filter a `@Component`. Since your `isAuthorized` method does nothing, you can straightaway bypass the filter for certain URLs by overriding the [shouldNotFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html#shouldNotFilter-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) method. And have you read the Javadoc for `HttpServletResponse`? Calling [reset](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#reset()) resets the status code, so this kinda code is useless `status == HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED || status == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK`.

I know this doesn't address the so-called infinite loop problem, but once you clean it up, you may not have such an issue. Last but not the least, help yourself with a debugger; you've the code, we don't.

Comment: i shifted to OncePerRequestFilter but the same problem exists

Comment: @jishnuradhakrishnan What about the other suggestions I made? What debugging have you done by yourself?